# C++: What type do I use for the definition of this map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, function-pointers

So, I have a function pointer defined as:

```
unsigned static int (*current_hash_function)(unsigned int);
```

And I'm trying to make a map of pointers to function names:

```
typedef std::map<fptr_t, std::string> function_map_t;
```

But I get this error:

> src/main.h:24: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `‘fptr_t’` with no type

Other code:

***main.h***:

```
typedef (*fptr_t)(unsigned int*);
typedef std::map<fptr_t, std::string> function_map_t;
function_map_t fmap;
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but... If your compiler supports some of the C++0x features, I'd suggest using std::function over typedefs for function pointers.  They'll be easier to read, and are more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function pointer's typedef is:

```
typedef unsigned int (*fptr_t)(unsigned int)
```

...then you can declare your map like this:

```
typedef std::map<fptr_t, std::string> function_map_t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "main.h" code doesn't give the function pointer typedef a return type. This works for me:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    typedef unsigned (*fptr_t)(unsigned);
    typedef std::map<fptr_t, std::string> function_map_t;
    function_map_t fmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the return type:

```
typedef int (*fptr_t)(unsigned int*);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to typedef the function pointer?

```
typedef unsigned int (*fptr_t)(unsigned int);
```

I believe thats the proper syntax

Comment: `unsigned static int` is nonsensical.

Comment: Thats true, I just copied his function footprint

Comment: It follows the format `typedef return_type (*name)(arg1_type, .., argN_type)` so you are correct I believe.

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't downvote it. ;-] Just pointing out that that *wasn't* proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your `typedef` for the function pointer is missing a return type:

```
typedef unsigned int (*fptr_t)(unsigned int *);
```

The above is a `typedef` for a pointer to a function that returns `unsigned int` and has an `unsigned int *` as a parameter.